# Event listener listener only working when I refresh the web page

Tags: javascript, event-handling

Am trying to create a web page with some FAQs. I have three buttons and each button has an event listener whereby when the button is clicked it changes the content of a div, everything is working perfectly when I click a button but when I try to click another button so that the content change the event listener isn't working unless I refresh the web page. How can I make the event listeners on all three buttons  work without refreshing the page?

Here's the code for one of the three buttons

```js
//First button code
const firstButton = document.querySelector('.faqs-link-firstbutton');
firstButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
  // Array of FAQ objects
  const FAQs = [{
      question: "What is Code ?",
      answer: "Giving instructions to the computer."
    },
    {
      question: "Can I change my Email ?",
      answer: "Yes you can change your email ."
    },
  ];
  // Create FAQ elements dynamically
  const faqContainer = document.querySelector('.faqs');
  FAQs.forEach((faq, index) => {
    const faqElement = document.createElement('div');
    faqElement.classList.add('faq');
    const questionElement = document.createElement('div');
    questionElement.classList.add('question');
    questionElement.innerText = ` ${faq.question}`;
    const answerElement = document.createElement('div');
    answerElement.classList.add('answer');
    answerElement.innerText = faq.answer;
    faqElement.appendChild(questionElement);
    faqElement.appendChild(answerElement);
    faqElement.addEventListener('click', () => {
      faqElement.classList.toggle('active');
    });
    faqContainer.appendChild(faqElement);
  });
  // Search FAQs
  const searchInput = document.getElementById('searchInput');
  searchInput.addEventListener('input', (event) => {
    const searchTerm = event.target.value.toLowerCase();
    const faqElements = document.querySelectorAll('.faq');
    faqElements.forEach((faqElement) => {
      const question = faqElement.querySelector('.question').innerText.toLowerCase();
      const answer = faqElement.querySelector('.answer').innerText.toLowerCase();
      if (question.includes(searchTerm) || answer.includes(searchTerm)) {
        faqElement.style.display = 'block';
      } else {
        faqElement.style.display = 'none';
      }
    });
  });
})
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you make that into a working snippet to reproduce the issue? Try adding a snippet using Ctrl-M

Comment: Can you explain what exactly should happen when you click your button? I have tested your code by creating two input tags and a div tag and when  I clicked on the button, all FAQs appeared each time I clicked on your button. You did not share your event listener for the other two buttons and did not explain what should happen when the user clicks on them. Please provide more information.

Comment: The code for the other buttons is similar to the first button. The only difference is the variable names and the id, everything else is just the same. So the buttons are like showing the topics  for the FAQs, I want when I click the button the FAQs change to the corresponding topic. Everything is working when I click a button for the first time but when I try to click on the other buttons nothing is working unless I refresh the web page.

Comment: Can you edit your question and add a Fiddle that reproduces the error? I'm trying to help you, but I do not understand what your actual problem is, because the question is too vague, lacks technical details. Please add a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please add relevant HTML and CSS